# Фиолетовая область в исследовании HTML

Tags: html, html5, вёрстка

Появилась фиолетовая область, как в F12, так и на сайте (прикрепил песочницу). Перепробовал много стилей, в частности width и margin для разных элементов, но почему-то мне кажется, что проблема в теге html. Как её убрать?

[image: моб. версия с display: block;]

[image: десктопная версия]

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};


var header = document.getElementById("header_top");

var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
}

.flex-container>div {
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.flex-container2 {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
}

.flex-container2>div {
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.flex-container3 {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
}

.flex-container3>div {
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%
}

.sticky+.content {
  padding-top: 102px;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  src: url("fonts/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Monserrato";
  src: url("fonts/Montserrat-Medium.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
}

h2 {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
}

h3 {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
}

p {
  font-family: "Monserrato";
  font-size: large;
}

li {
  font-family: "Monserrato";
  font-size: large;
}

a {
  font-family: "Monserrato";
}

A {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#content {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #FAFAFA;
}

hr {
  border: none;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  height: 75px;
  padding: 0px;
}

html {
  display: flex;
  width: 2236px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head style="width: 100%;">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FAFAFA">
  <header align="center" class="header">
    <div align="center" class="flex-container3" id="logocontacts">
      <!-- верхняя панель -->
      <div style="margin: 5px auto 0 1em">
        <!-- телефоны слева -->
        <p>068 831-95-69</p>
        <p>050 824-61-74</p>
        <p>044 334-31-80</p>
        <p>8 800 337 468</p>
      </div>
      <div style="margin: 0 auto;">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" class="center"></a>
      </div>
      <div style="margin: 5px 1em 0 auto;">
        <!-- адреса справа -->
        <p>г.Киев, ул.Борщаговская, 152а</p>
        <p>г.Киев, Харьковское шоссе,55</p>
        <p>Пн-Пт: 09:00–18:00</p>
        <p>Сб-Нд: выходной</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div align="center" class="flex-container2" id="header_top">
      <!-- панель навигации -->
      <div><a href="index.html">Головна</a></div>
      <div><a href="works.html">Наші роботи</a></div>
      <div><a href="sales.html">Акції</a></div>
      <div><a href="reviews.html">Відгуки</a></div>
      <div><a href="contacts.html">Контакти</a></div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div style="margin: auto;">
    <!-- главный центральный текст -->
    <h1>Металопластикові вікна, двері, перегородки у Києві та передмісті.</h1>
    <h1>Балкон під ключ.</h1>
    <h1>Пряма доставка з виробництва безкоштовно в Києві та передмісті</h1>
    <p>Наша команда виготовляє, доставляє і встановлює металопластикові вікна та алюмінієві конструкції різного рівня складності:</p>
    <p>від вікон або дверей або на балкон, до фасадних, офісних і торгових перегородок, тамбурів і веранд.</p>
    <p>Скління будинків, квартир, котеджів і дач.</p>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 100%">
    <div class="flex-container" align="center">
      <!-- типы продукции -->
      <div align="center">
        <h1 align="center"><a href="dom.html">Засклити будинок</a></h1>
        <a href="dom.html"><img src="img/dom.jpg"></a>
      </div>
      <div align="center">
        <h1 align="center"><a href="teracce.html">Засклити терасу</a></h1>
        <a href="teracce.html"><img src="img/teracce.jpg"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-container" align="center">
      <div align="center">
        <h1 align="center"><a href="kvartira.html">Засклити квартиру</a></h1>
        <a href="kvartira.html"><img src="img/kvartira.jpg"></a>
      </div>
      <div align="center">
        <h1 align="center"><a href="balconyonkey.html">Балкон під ключ</a></h1>
        <a href="balconyonkey.html"><img src="img/balconyonkey.jpg"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-container" align="center">
      <div align="center">
        <h1 align="center"><a href="peregorodki.html">Перегородки</a></h1>
        <a href="peregorodki.html"><img src="img/peregorodki.jpg"></a>
      </div>
      <div align="center">
        <h1 align="center"><a href="tambur.html">Засклити тамбур, ганок</a></h1>
        <a href="tambur.html"><img src="img/tambur.jpg"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-container" align="center">
      <div align="center">
        <h1 align="center"><a href="mp-door.html">Металопластикові двері</a></h1>
        <a href="mp-door.html"><img src="img/mp-door.jpg"></a>
      </div>
      <div align="center">
        <h1 align="center"><a href="mp-okna.html">Металопластикові вікна</a></h1>
        <a href="mp-okna.html"><img src="img/mp-okna.jpg"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

https://codepen.io/SiltyNiKE/pen/PojwMxG

Comment: div в сообщении в качестве обманки, оверфлов на кодпен ругаеться

Comment: `width: 2236px;` подобного не надо делать

Comment: Не задавайте `display: flex` тегу html.

Comment: Понимаете, если display будет block, там будет совершенно непонятная каша в мобильной версии (фото прикрепил). А по поводу width я уже понял. Но проблема в том, что width: 100% также не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам стоит изучить блочную модель: как именно блоки зависят от родительского элемента.
Достаточно убрать из body `display: flex;` и ширину, так никто не задаёт!
Обернуть всё, что ниже тега body в отдельный контейнер и задать определённые стили (всё может быть иначе, так как смотрел в песочнице)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```